# How can I get the multiple classes in span with beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get classes of span in `<p>` with beautifulsoup.

HTML is somewhat like this

```
...
<p class="card-list">
<span class="span1 class1"></span>
<span class="span2 class2"></span>
<span class="span3 class3"></span>
<span class="span4 class4"></span>
</p>
```

Code I am using is

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), "html.parser")
services = soup.find_all('li', {'class': 'card-list'})

for eachclass in services:
    classes = []
    for spans in eachclass.find('p', {'class':'card-info'}):
        for element in spans.find_all(class_=True):
            classes.extend(element["class"])
        print(classes)
```

The output I am getting is

```
classes = ["span1", "class1", "span2", "class2","span3", class3","span4", "class4"]
```

What I want is

```
classes = ["span1 class1", "span2 class2","span3 class3","span4 class4"]
```

There are other `<span>` also. I just need classes of `<span>` in `<p class="card-list">` Tag.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you done any debugging?

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
cards = """
<p class="card-list">
<span class="span1 class1"></span>
<span class="span2 class2"></span>
<span class="span3 class3"></span>
<span class="span4 class4"></span>
</p>
"""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
soup = bs(cards,'lxml')
classes = []
for c in soup.select('span'):
    elem = ' '.join(map(str, c['class'])) 
    classes.append(elem)
print(classes)
```

Output:

> ['span1 class1', 'span2 class2', 'span3 class3', 'span4 class4']

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """
<p class="card-list">
<span class="span1 class1"></span>
<span class="span2 class2"></span>
<span class="span3 class3"></span>
<span class="span4 class4"></span>
</p>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
allclasses = []
for item in soup.find('p',class_='card-list').find_all('span'):
    classes=' '.join(item.attrs['class'])
    allclasses.append(classes)
print(allclasses)
```

**Output**:

```
['span1 class1', 'span2 class2', 'span3 class3', 'span4 class4']
```

---

**Updated**

```
allclasses = []
for item in soup.select("p[class='contact-info '] span[class]"):
    classes=' '.join(item.attrs['class'])
    allclasses.append(classes)
print(allclasses)
```

Comment: KeyError: 'class' on classes=' '.join(item.attrs['class'])

Comment: This shouldn't happen.can you share your url?

Comment: @Ganesh : Try updated solution and let me know the status.

Comment: URL is shorturl.at/mABES, I am trying to get Span class from <p class="contact-info ">

Comment: Error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all' on for item in soup.find('p',class_='card-list').find_all('span'):

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210396/discussion-between-kunduk-and-ganesh).

Comment: It returns empty array

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating one list and appending both `class` of each `span` and then joining them with `' '.join(listname)` 
LaterI added that list to another list.

Answer (score 0):

Solutions using library SimplifiedDoc.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,req,utils
html='''
<li class="card-list">
<p class="card-info">
<span class="span1 class1"></span>
<span class="span2 class2"></span>
<span class="span3 class3"></span>
<span class="span4 class4"></span>
</p>
</li>'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
classes = doc.selects('li.card-list').select('p.card-info').selects('span>class()')
print (classes)
```

Result:

```
[['span1 class1', 'span2 class2', 'span3 class3', 'span4 class4']]
```